# groceryCRUD datatable width issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, datatables, grocery-crud

I have doubt about the data table theme of grocery CRUD library. Since i have many fields on my database tables, it seems it overlap on the div tag where i put the $output variable where it prints the data of the table. I am currently using App UI 2.1 bootstrap theme.

**asssets/grocery_crud/themes/datatables/js/database.js**

```
var default_per_page = typeof default_per_page !== 'undefined' ?             default_per_page : 25;
var oTable = null;
var oTableArray = [];
var oTableMapping = [];

function supports_html5_storage()
{
try {
    JSON.parse("{}");
    return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
} catch (e) {
    return false;
}
}

var use_storage = supports_html5_storage();

var aButtons = [];
var mColumns = [];

$(document).ready(function () {

$('table.groceryCrudTable').dataTable( {
   "scrollX": true 
});

$('table.groceryCrudTable thead tr th').each(function (index) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('actions'))
    {
        mColumns[index] = index;
    }
});

if (!unset_export)
{
    aButtons.push({
        "sExtends": "xls",
        "sButtonText": export_text,
        "mColumns": mColumns
    });
}

if (!unset_print)
{
    aButtons.push({
        "sExtends": "print",
        "sButtonText": print_text,
        "mColumns": mColumns
    });
}

//For mutliplegrids disable bStateSave as it is causing many problems
if ($('.groceryCrudTable').length > 1) {
    use_storage = false;
}

$('.groceryCrudTable').each(function (index) {
    if (typeof oTableArray[index] !== 'undefined') {
        return false;
    }

    oTableMapping[$(this).attr('id')] = index;

    oTableArray[index] = loadDataTable(this);
});

$(".groceryCrudTable tfoot input").keyup(function () {

    chosen_table =     datatables_get_chosen_table($(this).closest('.groceryCrudTable'));

    chosen_table.fnFilter(this.value, chosen_table.find("tfoot input").index(this));

    if (use_storage)
    {
        var search_values_array = [];

        chosen_table.find("tfoot tr th").each(function (index, value) {
            search_values_array[index] = $(this).children(':first').val();
        });

        localStorage.setItem('datatables_search_' + unique_hash, '["' + search_values_array.join('","') + '"]');
    }
});

var search_values = localStorage.getItem('datatables_search_' + unique_hash);

if (search_values !== null)
{
    $.each($.parseJSON(search_values), function (num, val) {
        if (val !== '')
        {
            $(".groceryCrudTable tfoot tr th:eq(" + num + ")").children(':first').val(val);
        }
    });
}

$('.clear-filtering').click(function () {
    localStorage.removeItem('DataTables_' + unique_hash);
    localStorage.removeItem('datatables_search_' + unique_hash);

    chosen_table = datatables_get_chosen_table($(this).closest('.groceryCrudTable'));

    chosen_table.fnFilterClear();
    $(this).closest('.groceryCrudTable').find("tfoot tr th input").val("");
});

loadListenersForDatatables();

$('a[role=button],button[role=button]').live("mouseover mouseout", function (event) {
    if (event.type == "mouseover") {
        $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
    }
});

$('th.actions').unbind('click');
$('th.actions>div .DataTables_sort_icon').remove();

});

function loadListenersForDatatables() {

$('.refresh-data').click(function () {
    var this_container = $(this).closest('.dataTablesContainer');

    var new_container = $("<div/>").addClass('dataTablesContainer');

    this_container.after(new_container);
    this_container.remove();

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('data-url'),
        success: function (my_output) {
            new_container.html(my_output);

            loadDataTable(new_container.find('.groceryCrudTable'));

            loadListenersForDatatables();
        }
    });
});
}

function loadDataTable(this_datatables) {
return $(this_datatables).dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bStateSave": use_storage,
    "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
        localStorage.setItem('DataTables_' + unique_hash, JSON.stringify(oData));
    },
    "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DataTables_' + unique_hash));
    },
    "iDisplayLength": default_per_page,
    "aaSorting": datatables_aaSorting,
    "oLanguage": {
        "sProcessing": list_loading,
        "sLengthMenu": show_entries_string,
        "sZeroRecords": list_no_items,
        "sInfo": displaying_paging_string,
        "sInfoEmpty": list_zero_entries,
        "sInfoFiltered": filtered_from_string,
        "sSearch": search_string + ":",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst": paging_first,
            "sPrevious": paging_previous,
            "sNext": paging_next,
            "sLast": paging_last
        }
    },
    "bDestory": true,
    "bRetrieve": true,
    "fnDrawCallback": function () {
        $('.image-thumbnail').fancybox({
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'elastic',
            'speedIn': 600,
            'speedOut': 200,
            'overlayShow': false
        });
        add_edit_button_listener();
    },
    "sDom": 'T<"clear"><"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',
    "oTableTools": {
        "aButtons": aButtons,
        "sSwfPath": base_url + "assets/grocery_crud/themes/datatables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
    }
});
}

function datatables_get_chosen_table(table_as_object)
{
chosen_table_index = oTableMapping[table_as_object.attr('id')];
return oTableArray[chosen_table_index];
}

function delete_row(delete_url, row_id)
{
if (confirm(message_alert_delete))
{
    $.ajax({
        url: delete_url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data)
        {
            if (data.success)
            {
                success_message(data.success_message);

                chosen_table = datatables_get_chosen_table($('tr#row-' + row_id).closest('.groceryCrudTable'));

                $('tr#row-' + row_id).addClass('row_selected');
                var anSelected = fnGetSelected(chosen_table);
                chosen_table.fnDeleteRow(anSelected[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                error_message(data.error_message);
            }
        }
    });
}

return false;
}

function fnGetSelected(oTableLocal)
{
var aReturn = new Array();
var aTrs = oTableLocal.fnGetNodes();

for (var i = 0; i < aTrs.length; i++)
{
    if ($(aTrs[i]).hasClass('row_selected'))
    {
        aReturn.push(aTrs[i]);
    }
}
return aReturn;
}
```

**controller/InfoTable.php**

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Infotable extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('grocery_CRUD');
}

public function residents() {
    $this->_example_output((object) array('output' => '', 'js_files' => array(), 'css_files' => array()));
}

public function index() {
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

    $crud->set_subject('Resident');
    $crud->set_table('resident');
    $crud->set_theme('datatables');
    $crud->columns('name', 'mname', 'lname', 'gender', 'bday', 'age', 'citizenship', 'occupation', 'status', 'purok', 'resAddress', 'perAddress', 'email', 'telNum', 'cpNum');
    $crud->set_primary_key('resident_id', 'resident');

    $crud->display_as('name', 'First Name')
            ->display_as('mname', 'Middle Name')
            ->display_as('lname', 'Last Name')
            ->display_as('gender', 'Gender')
            ->display_as('bday', 'Birthdate')
            ->display_as('age', 'Age')
            ->display_as('citizenship', 'Citizenship')
            ->display_as('occupation', 'Occupation')
            ->display_as('status', 'Status')
            ->display_as('purok', 'Purok')
            ->display_as('resAddress', 'Residential Address')
            ->display_as('perAddress', 'Permanent Address')
            ->display_as('email', 'Email Address')
            ->display_as('telNum', 'Tel. #')
            ->display_as('cpNum', 'Cellphone #');

    $output = $crud->render();

    $this->_example_output($output);
}

function _example_output($output = null) {
    $this->load->view('Backend/page_ui_tables', $output);
}

}
```

what i'm trying to get here is i want to add scrollX option on the datatables theme on the library but it seems the css and js functions of the theme will damage/malfunction. i think that it's the bootstrap theme that damaging it.

Any help will much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Nobody would be able to help without the code and some explanation, please see [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i finished edited the question, my apology for incomplete requirements of asking. my net slows down that's why i accidentally submit it, if you help me with my issue it should  be a blessing, thanks :)

Comment: If you want to add `scrollX` parameter, add it in the `dataTable ()` call in `loadDataTable()` function. There is no sense to call  `$('table.groceryCrudTable').dataTable( { "scrollX": true });` because you later re-initialize the table without the `scrollX` parameter. You also need to be clear what **damage/malfunction** means.

Comment: ok i get it now, and sorry again for my worst grammar. thank you so much!